# How to access raid partitions after controller failure

Tags: gentoo, raid

I'm running Gentoo on a `Fujitsu Primergy RX200 S7`. Initially had 2 SAS drives on a PRAID eP400-i controller. Suddenly, the controller seems to have died, leaving me with no choice, but to use the server's integrated LSI MegaRAID SAS controller (which by the way, requires a SAS enabling key for SAS drives to work).
Can someone point me in the right direction, as to how do i get access to my partitions again?

I tried booting from a gentoo live install dvd. Loaded all the modules related to SAS and recompiled the kernel. Couldn't reboot, so I modeprobe'd each module manually, but still... no new drive in `/dev/disk/`.

I thought of installing a fresh gentoo with all the modules and firmware's, on a VM, and try a LAN boot, or even adding a SATA drive to the server and installing there. Maybe it needs a reboot, and I can't do it from a live cd.

`lspci -k|grep SAS` shows a `Serial Attached SCSI controller: Intel corporation C600/x79 series chipset 4-port SATA/SAS Storage Control Unit`, but no module in use, so it makes sense that I don't see my RAID drive, so... what module do I need? How to best approach this issue? Been banging my head for 3 days now.

Comment: As i know not all raid controllers are compatible with each other. You have to get the same model what was wrecked. By the way i'm really wondering on people who uses hw raid in XXI. century. SW raid is better in all cases - for example recovery.

Comment: Its not a matter of compatibility. I can see the drives, and the raid config is properly imported by the new controller. My problem is that i cannot find drivers for it. None of the distros i used see the raid drive. I agree about the sw raid, but first i have to recover the data and then go softr...

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Ping me via robbat2@gentoo.org, as genkernel author & someone with input as to what kernel options the livedvd media has (it doesn't have every single SAS controller).